# How to make an inflated cloth object roll like a rigid object

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, cloth-simulation

When a rigid body interacts with an object, it will roll in a realistic manner. The animation below illustrates this effect.

[image]

If a similar simulation is setup with a cloth object that is inflated, to keep it stiff, the object doesn't roll like expected. It has too much sliding rather than rolling.

[image]

Are there ways to setup the cloth simulation so it will realistically roll?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, just increase your friction of the collision object (half sphere) like this:

[image]

and you get:

[image]

[image]

[image]